# format numbers on ios

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking for a way to format a string into number and show it on textfield

For example: I have the number `"1000"`, I want to it convert into `"1.000"` or `100000` into `100.000`.  Or `1000000` into `1.000.000`. Please help me if you know solution for this

Thanks

Comment: None of your examples represent currency. Those are simply formatted numbers, not currency.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the NSNumberFormatter class as follows.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringForObjectValue:@2333999878]);
```

This class is very powerful and will also allow you to localize the currency beside the formatting

Comment: Technically, he wants to format it as Currency (given the title of the question) so you should be using `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`...

Comment: @DaveDeLong Not a single example in the OP's question actually shows a desire for currency formatting despite the title.

Comment: @rmaddy besides his first sentence? "I'm looking for a way to format a string into currency"

Comment: @DaveDeLong I'm just saying, not a single one of the OP's examples are actually currency formats. You have an anonymous new user posting a somewhat conflicting question. Until it's clarified, it may be premature to down vote an answer that may turn out to be correct.

Comment: @rmaddy fair enough. down vote rescinded

Comment: I think I wrote the title of question incorrect. I simply want to format numbers similar to the example above that I've posted. I think it is not related to the currency. Sr for my bad english

Comment: @eharo2 - The last line of your answer should use `stringFromNumber:`, not `stringForObjectValue:`.

Comment: @user3525058 I've updated your question to indicate that you don't want to format currency values.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to format a number as currency, then you need to use `NSNumberFormatter`. However, the other answers are wrong because they tell you to use the wrong `numberStyle` or tell you to change the format string. These are both incorrect.

First, you want an `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
```

Next, you need to tell it you're going to be formatting things for currency:

```
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
```

Optionally, if you want things to be formatted in a specific currency, you *may* set the currency code:

```
formatter.currencyCode = @"USD";
```

Optionally, if you want things to be formatted according to the locale settings that are not the user's default locale, you *may* set the locale:

```
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
```

If you were to run those four lines of code, you would get an `NSNumberFormatter` that formats an `NSNumber` in US Dollars, but according to the Great Britain locale. The locale is what defines the placement of the currency symbol (before or after the number), the decimal separator (`.` vs `,`), the thousands separator (`,` vs ), and so on.

The currency code defines what the currency symbol is (`$` vs `£`, etc).

By default, the locale is `[NSLocale currentLocale]`, and the currency code is the code for the current locale.

One very very very important thing to remember, however, is that this only *formats* currency for you. It does *not* perform any currency *conversion* for you. It assumes that whatever `NSNumber` you give it is *already* in units of the target currency.

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"#.###"];
NSString *string = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1000]];
```

Comment: -1 incorrect. You should not change the number format strings.

Comment: why should not? enlighten me @DaveDeLong

Comment: because the `locale` property already contains all of that, and will account for regional variants and user-customized settings. Watch any of the Internationalization sessions from previous WWDCs. They all go into this very topic in depth.

Comment: thanks for the enlightenment Dave. but, is there a currency value with a format "1.000.000"? (take note of the dot(.)) i think the title and the description of the question is a bit ambiguous. nevertheless, i'll take note your answer. :D

Comment: @mownier The answer by eharo2 will give a result like "1.000.000" if the user is in a locale that uses the "." for the grouping separator. Or it will give "1,000,000" if the user is in a locale that uses "," for the grouping separator. That's why you shouldn't set a specific format. Let the number formatter format the number appropriately for the user's locale. The OP probably lives where "." is the grouping separator. It's unlikely that the OP really wants every user, regardless of where they live, to see numbers with a "." grouping separator.

Comment: thanks for elaborating more @rmaddy